# remove parentElement and saving changes when reload again

Tags: javascript, html, removechild, items

Html code

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="row">
    <p>anything</p>
    <input type="button" id="1" class="Done" name="Go" value="done">
  </div>

   <div class="row">
     <p>anything</p>
     <input type="button" id="2" class="Done" name="Go" value="done">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <p>anything</p>
     <input type="button" id="3" class="Done" name="Go" value="done">
   </div>

 </div>
```

I have 3 of them[buttons]

javascript

```
var remove=document.getElementsByClassName("Done")

for(var i=0;i<remove.length;i++){
    var button=remove[i]
    button.addEventListener('click',function(event){
        var bclick = event.target
        bclick.parentElement.remove()


    });
}
```

I tried that, it's work for the first time but when I reload I miss changes.

Comment: question is not clear, this code works i tried it on a fiddle, what else are you missing?

Comment: yes it works  removing elements from the page but when  I reload the page every thing appears again. I want it to remove Element and save the page .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use localstorage to track your removed parentElement. Simply check your localstorage whether your parentElement is removed or not, if it is removed already just hide your row class's elements. It will show nothing once button is clicked. Hope it will help.

```js
var remove = document.getElementsByClassName("Done");

for (var i = 0; i < remove.length; i++) {

  var button = remove[i];

  if (button) {

    if (window.localStorage.getItem(remove[i].id) == 'true') {

      document.getElementById(remove[i].id).parentNode.style.display = 'none';

    }
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < remove.length; i++) {

  var button = remove[i];

  if (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      var bclick = event.target;
      window.localStorage.setItem(bclick.id, 'true');
      bclick.parentElement.remove();

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: it's worked with the first element and then the page stuck there.

Comment: I think when you remove the element after clicking the button you want to save that you have already removed the element, isn't it? The page doesn't stuck there, when you click the button it saves in the local storage that you remove the element and after you reload the page you will not able to see the button.

Comment: If I miss anything, let me know.

Comment: yes  but I have many  buttons and i want  this method to work with all of them.

Comment: It would be better if you share your code and explain when you hide or show a button. I thought you wanted this only for the given button.

Comment: it's like this   `code`<div class="cont">
  <div class="row">
      <p>anything</p>
      <input type="button" class="Done" name="Go" value="done">
  </div>
 <div class="row">
      <p>anything</p>
      <input type="button" class="Done" name="Go" value="done">
  </div>
 <div class="row">
      <p>anything</p>
      <input type="button" class="Done" name="Go" value="done">
  </div>
</div>

Comment: @BMarquiz98, I have edited my solution above. Please check this out and let me know. I have solved this according to your given code.

Comment: I think you missed a thing, all of your three buttons are same, use id to differentiate between buttons. Thank you.

Comment: This is the edited html: ```<div class="cont">
      <div class="row">
        <p>anything</p>
        <input type="button" id="1" class="Done" name="Go" value="done">
      </div>

       <div class="row">
         <p>anything</p>
         <input type="button" id="2" class="Done" name="Go" value="done">
       </div>
       <div class="row">
         <p>anything</p>
         <input type="button" id="3" class="Done" name="Go" value="done">
       </div>

     </div>```

Comment: it's woking 100% thank you very much it's solved my problem

Comment: @BMarquiz98, My pleasure :)