# Delete HTML element persistently for specific page / domain in Chomium-based browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

## Background

This question may look similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59127124/remove-parentelement-and-saving-changes-when-reload-again), but in fact it is not, please read further.

In a specific web page (let's say, `example.com`), there's a specific `div` element with some unique attribute, e.g. `<div some-label="Some text">`. I want to delete this element through by Chrome-based browser. Using the Developer Tools, I can simply click on this element and push `DEL`, and voila! the nagging element's gone. But only until I reload the page!

## Question

Is it possible to delete this element *permanently* in my browser? In more exact wording:

> Using a *Chrome-based* browser, what are the steps (*if* they exist) to make an arbitrary HTML element *disappear* on a *specific website* (or domain), *surviving* browser / tab / page reloads?

I realize it must be some JS script hooked on some global browser events (like tab reload). But I simply don't know how to do that and will be happy if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should create your [own extension](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/development-basics/#build) to remove the element when page load. or more simple, use chrome extension, [ublock origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm) and [register a filter](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-block-content-from-web-pages-using-ublock-origin/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the question was, how to do that without any external plugins?

Comment: @s0mbre, as far as i know, you can't or you can but you need to modify the browser itself